# How to select first class in a list of class definition for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these elements :

```
<div id="contentoDinamico">    
    <div id="item_box_3777" class="index0 itemContenutoDinamico attivo">
    <div id="item_box_3792" class="index4 itemContenutoDinamico">
</div>
```

and this function :

```
$("#contentoDinamico div").attr('class', function(i, e) {
    a.push(e);
});
```

but I'd like to push only first class for each div child; 
so, in the example, `index0` and `index4`, not `index0 itemContenutoDinamico attivo` and `index4 itemContenutoDinamico`.

How can I do this?

Comment: The `function (i, e)` should be **returning** values.

Comment: ? I cant get all attr if I return values...

Comment: `.attr(key, func)` is for _setting_ values, not _getting_ them.

Comment: I mean get from DOM to array; so yes, set to the array :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 compatible browsers add a `classList` property to elements which you can index directly.  Alternatively you'd have to split the class value by space characters:

```
$("#contentoDinamico div").each(function(i, e) {
     if ('classList' in this) {
         a.push(this.classList[0]);
     } else {
         var cn = this.className;
         var ca = cn.split(' ');
         a.push(c[0]);
     }
}
```

The space splitting version might break if you have leading spaces in your class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Split the class that you return by a space, and then there you have it:

```
.split(/\s/)
```